# How to assign Class name to $variable function

Tags: php, oop

In Laravel you can use :

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
function(request $request)
{
    // Code
}
```

I want create class like this :

```
namespace demo;
 class OK
 {
    function b(){
        return "OK";
    }
 }
 use demo\OK;
 function bla(OK $a){
    return $a->b();
 }
echo bla();
```

But it not work. Something wrong here ?

Comment: you forgot to instantiate then pass $a into your `bla();` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `bla` accepts **one** argument, so call should be something like:

```
use demo\OK;
function bla(OK $a){
   return $a->b();
}

$new_ok = new OK();
echo bla($new_ok);
```

Comment: If using like this I don't need add OK class name to  `function bla(OK $a){ // code }`. I want don't use $new_ok = new OK(); like Laravel do ?